# Seaborn: lineplot looks like a step plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, visualization, seaborn

I'm trying to build a line plot with Seaborn in Jupyter Notebook, using the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# load csv
df=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/1/Desktop/graphs/seaborn/Data.csv')
# make sure date is in datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m-%d-%y')
# generate graph
g = sns.lineplot(x="Date", y="Data", data=df)

plt.show()
```

However, the result looks like this:
[image]

whereas the desired output is as follows (built in Excel):
[image]

What argument am I missing in order to make the plot smoother?

The .csv looks like this:

```
Date,Data
01-09-97,
01-10-97,
01-11-97,
01-12-97,
01-01-98,
01-02-98,
01-03-98,
01-04-98,
01-05-98,309.5
01-06-98,
...
01-07-14,44726.5
01-08-14,45735.1
01-09-14,47430
01-10-14,49887.7
01-11-14,51799.5
01-12-14,54258.1
01-01-15,52079.1
01-02-15,51110.6
01-03-15,49614.8
01-04-15,49989.2
```

Comment: Can you share the data for us to be able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: How should I do it? Here is a link to .csv file on google drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VmI2QweaWDGalxU86EhmYYI7pdL4PypH

Comment: Either you can share some minimal data by editing your question or you can upload the file online and share some link.

Comment: @СтепанСмирнов It may be because you have large chunks of no data near the beginning of the file. I would suggest taking out the csv file lines that don't have any data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple mistake, your date format is not `%m-%d-%y`, but `%d-%m-%y`:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# load csv
df=pd.read_csv("test.csv")
# make sure date is in datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%m-%y')
# generate graph
g = sns.lineplot(x="Date", y="Data", data=df)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]